# Is "composition over inheritance" simply mean "If parent class is never be used except in child class, it should be composition"?

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, language-agnostic, composition

I read some posts about "composition over inheritance","where to use composition/inheritance" , "Is-a relationship..." or "Liskov substitution principle" for some time, but I am not sure if I get the right idea about "composition over inheritance".

Alternatively, In my experience, "composition over inheritance" seems just mean "If parent class is never be used except by child class, it should be composition", for example:

```
public class Parent{
}

public class Child1 extends Parent{
}

public class Child2 extends Parent{
}
```

If class "Parent" is never appeared at my code other than in Child1 and Child2, then Child1 and Child2 should not be the child class of Parent.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I generally find that when re-use is the goal, inheritance is attractive. However, in this situation, composition always turns out to be the better solution. For me, inheritance is best used for its polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Composition-over-inheritance means that instead of structuring your class hierarchy using a parent class and `extend`ing child classes, you should do something like this:

```
class Foo {

    protected bar;
    protected baz;

    public function Foo(Bar _bar, Baz _baz) {
        bar = _bar;
        baz = _baz;
    }

}
```

In other words, instead of *inheriting* a bunch of functionality from a base parent class, you get this same functionality from independent objects instead which you preferably dependency inject into your class.

Why? Because it provides more flexibility. In the case of `Foo extends Bar`, `Bar` provides some base functionality which is useful for a bunch of inheriting classes. Now, who says this functionality isn't also useful for a bunch of other, unrelated classes? Should *all* your classes inherit from `Bar`? Should *all* common functionality be stuffed into `Bar` because all classes inherit from it? Please no, that just leads to fat, monolithic, unmaintainable base classes.

Instead, implement any collection of useful common methods in their own independent class. Group only functionality which is closely related, separate into different classes as makes sense. Then inject those objects into other objects to *compose* a new object which can use all that shared functionality without inheriting monolithic base classes or defining an abstract strict class hierarchy.

You should only inherit a class if they share the same "business logic" hierarchy. E.g., `Cat extends Pet extends Animal` makes perfectly logical sense. `Cat extends BaseConnectionManager` less so.

If you're using class hierarchies for type hinting, interfaces can serve this purpose much better and more flexibly too.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is a specific tool.  Composition is a general tool.  Both are useful, but in different contexts.

Inheritance is useful when you want to ensure that all objects of type Foo are also, in every respect, objects of type Bar.  This means more than just implementing the same methods.  It means Foo objects must *perfectly* emulate Bar objects in every outwardly-visible respect.  If they do not, then the Liskov Substitution Principle is violated, and inheritance is a poor choice for the situation at hand.

Composition is much more general.  It is used to divide responsibilities among multiple classes while still allowing for properly abstracted and defined interactions between them.  It does not require the specific, Liskov-like relationship I just described.

"Composition over inheritance" is just the observation that composition is a more general technique than inheritance.  Because of this, composition should be the tool we reach for first in most situations, rather than inheritance.  This does not mean that every use of inheritance is wrong, or even that inheritance is inherently bad.  It's a way of thinking, not a coding standard.